# How to use 2 conditions in an if statement in html

Tags: html

I've looked everywhere Google leads me and found no answers. Help? Also, another question is how do I make a condition to check whether a textbox is filled with something or is left blank. I'm sorry for the n00b questions. I'm really new to html and programming in general. Thanks!

Comment: you should use a script language for this, jquery or javascript.

Comment: you need to learn JavaScript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: HTML is markup language not a programming language, you can't use conditions in HTML unless you use JavaScript. JavaScript is a programming language.

Answer (score 2):

HTML is a markup language and doesn't have if statements. You'd need to use JavaScript to check whether something has a value.

Check out [MDN's article on if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) for more information.